# Why data cannot be inserted from Android Apps to MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have created my database MySQL and I wish to send data from the android apps into the database but I couldn't do so. I am using wamp server.

Here are my php code:

```
<?php mysql_connect("localhost","cupcake","123456");
mysql_select_db("cindy");
$sql=mysql_query("insert into yang (name)values('".$_REQUEST['i_name']."')");
$r=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$r)echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();mysql_close();?>
```

Here is my Java file from Android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        String result = null;
        JSONArray jArray;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("i_name","aaa"));
        try{     

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/testing.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            }



        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             sb = new StringBuilder();
             sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
             String line="0";
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");        }
              is.close();
              result=sb.toString();
              }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
              }//paring datatry


        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
           //int[] deal_id=new int[jArray.length()+1];
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                   json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            }
            }      catch(JSONException e1){
                   } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();   }
          }}
```

This is the MySQL table that i have craeted

```
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yang` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
)
```

Please help me.. Thanks...

Comment: And what do you get? Any errors?

Comment: @ Thilo, I didnt gt any errors... my code can work, bt there is no data in my table..

Answer (score 0):

This sort of development can be pretty hard to debug, so I would always use lots of logging.

For example, in your PHP add:

error_log("Inserting name: " . $_REQUEST['i_name']);

Then you can check the server error log to make sure you're getting what you expect. Keep adding logging statements till you find the problem.

PS: I'm not an expert on PHP but it looks to me like your PHP would be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack so you probably wouldn't want to deploy this!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should try to include as much logging as you can to see what is going on.

I am assuming you are deploying this Android app to your phone or emulator, correct? In the native browser can you go to http:// 10.0.2.2 /testing.php and verify that this is not a local network connection issue?

Also, have you independently tested your PHP code? Are you sure it works?

Lastly, your PHP script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You never want to concatenate any data like that from your user directly into a SQL statement. Use a prepared statement to handle this. PHP has a PDO library that you can use. Here is a tutorial (http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html) - there are many others you can follow. Just Google PHP PDO prepared statement tutorial or something

Let me know what answers you find to the above questions.

Comment: phone or emulator?  10.0.2.2 only works on emulators **not on real devices**  But checking in the browser is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving localhost address in android java file i.e 10.0.2.2 and in my knowledge it doesn't work. open command prompt and type ipconfig and press Enter. After than check your ip v4 address which would be starting like 192.168.... copy that address and in search bar if the project is running than replace the localhost ip with this one. Actually android takes domain name not localhost. and change in to android java file with that also. hope it will work. Thanks